# character Counting in apache

Tags: apache

I have few text files and I'm looking to count letters in all those text files combined in total. For example text1.txt contains "Stackoverflow is so cool". I'm looking to get the total letter count

Comment: It would be nice to see what you have tried. You must rather show what you have tried and where you are getting struck.

Answer (score 0):

Load all the files using wildcard character * into field of type chararray.Split the line into words and then into letters and count them.

```
A = LOAD '/path/text*.txt' AS (lines:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(lines))) AS words;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(words,'','|'), '|')) AS letters;
D = GROUP C BY letters;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE COUNT(C), group;
DUMP E;
```

Comment: Thanks! If I were to find count specific letters and not the whole set of alphabets. For example just a, b and c. Then how would this query will change?

Comment: Add a step to filter relation C to get a new relation, say C1 = FILTER C BY (letters matches '.*(a|b|c).*'); and then replace C with C1 in subsequent steps.

Comment: Thanks! But the thing is it is giving different counts for lower case and upper case letters. I want a&A to be treated same. How do I make it case insensitive?

Comment: Use LOWER in any of the first 3 steps on lines or words or letters i.e. before grouping.I've updated the script.